# Android Studio Wrong 1st argument type. Found 'java.lang.String', required 'int'

Tags: java, android

Good Day

I have search the website but could not get anything to help me in my problem.
I`m a newby to android and started a project that I just can not complete.

using Android Studio 2.3
app name "Match Tracker"

Ok here it go's
example my app allows you to track a match "Rugby" now I would like the app to auto add points to the leader board if a team has 4 or more tries and that is where I get stuck!!

my FactDBAdaptor.class

EDITED*******

```
    package za.co.sanrl.rugbyleague.database;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import za.co.sanrl.rugbyleague.main.MatchEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Class that allows interaction with the Facts database such as insert, delete, update.
 *
 * @author Morne van Rooyen
 */
public class FactsDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_MATCHID  = "match_id";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE     = "type";
    public static final String KEY_PLAYER1  = "player1";
    public static final String KEY_PLAYER2  = "player2";
    public static final String KEY_TEAM     = "team";
    public static final String KEY_TIME     = "time";
    private static final String DB_TABLE    = "Facts";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private BaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Context context;

    public FactsDbAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Open database so we can write to it.
     *
     * @return Open DB connection
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public FactsDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new BaseHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Close database.
     */
    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Add a match fact to the database.
     *
     * @param match_id Match ID
     * @param type     Goal, penalty etc.
     * @param player1  First player involved in event
     * @param player2  Second player involved in event
     * @param team     The player(s) team
     * @param time     The time event took place
     */
    public void addMatchFact(int match_id, String type, String player1, String player2, String team, String time) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MATCHID, match_id);
        values.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        values.put(KEY_PLAYER1, player1);
        values.put(KEY_PLAYER2, player2);
        values.put(KEY_TEAM, team);
        values.put(KEY_TIME, time);

        //Insert into database.
        try {
            db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Database error when inserting match fact", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the column values for a specific column provided.
     *
     * @param column     - column you want to query.
     * @param duplicates - if you want duplicate results.
     * @return columnlist
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getColumnValues(String column, boolean duplicates) {
        Cursor cursor                   = null;
        ArrayList<String> columnList    = new ArrayList<>();

        //Get column values.
        try {
            if (duplicates) {
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + column + " FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);
            } else {
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " + column + " FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Database error selecting facts", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Query result is not empty.
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column);

            do {
                columnList.add(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return columnList;
    }

    /**
     * Count number of types with a given match_id.
     *
     * @param match_id Match ID
     * @param type     Event Type
     * @param teamName Team Name
     * @return count of types
     */
    public int countTypesWithMatchID(int match_id, String type, String teamName) {
        Cursor cursor                   = null;
        ArrayList<String> columnList    = new ArrayList<>();

        //Get column values.
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_TYPE + " FROM " + DB_TABLE +
                    " WHERE " + KEY_TYPE + "=? AND " + KEY_MATCHID + "=" + match_id +
                    " AND " + KEY_TEAM + "=?", new String[]{type, teamName});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Database error counting match events", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Query result is not empty.
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int typeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);

            do {
                columnList.add(cursor.getString(typeIndex));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return columnList.size();
    }
/**Count 4 or more tries in a match begins**/
    /**
     * Count number of types with a given match_id.
     *
     * @param match_id Match ID
     * @param type     type is Tries
     * @param teamName Team Name
     * @return count of types
     */
    public int countTriesWithMatchID(int match_id, String type, String teamName) {
        Cursor cursor   = null;
        int result      = 0;

        //Get column values.
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(" + KEY_TYPE + ") FROM " + DB_TABLE +
                    " WHERE " + KEY_TYPE + "=Try AND " + KEY_MATCHID + "=" + match_id +
                    " AND " + KEY_TEAM + "=?", new String[]{type, teamName});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Database error counting match events", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Query result is not empty.
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result = cursor.getInt(0);
        }

        return result;
    }

/**Count 4 or more tries in a match ends**/


    /**
     * Count the number a certain type with a certain player name comes up in db.
     *
     * @param type   Event Type
     * @param player Player involved in event
     * @return count of types involving a specific player
     */
    public int countTypesWithPlayer(String type, String player) {
        Cursor cursor   = null;
        int result      = 0;

        //Get column values.
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(" + KEY_TYPE + ") FROM " + DB_TABLE +
                            " WHERE " + KEY_TYPE + "=? AND " + KEY_PLAYER1 + "=?", new String[]{type, player});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Db err counting type of events involving a player", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Query result is not empty.
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result = cursor.getInt(0);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Get all match facts for a given match id.
     *
     * @param match_id Match ID
     * @return All match facts
     */
    public ArrayList<MatchEvent> getAllFactsForGivenMatchID(int match_id) {
        Cursor cursor                   = null;
        ArrayList<MatchEvent> result    = new ArrayList<>();

        //Get column values.
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE match_id=" + match_id, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Db err select * events", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Query result is not empty.
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int typeIndex       = cursor.getColumnIndex(FactsDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE);
            int player1Index    = cursor.getColumnIndex(FactsDbAdapter.KEY_PLAYER1);
            int player2Index    = cursor.getColumnIndex(FactsDbAdapter.KEY_PLAYER2);
            int teamIndex       = cursor.getColumnIndex(FactsDbAdapter.KEY_TEAM);
            int timeIndex       = cursor.getColumnIndex(FactsDbAdapter.KEY_TIME);

            do {
                String type         = cursor.getString(typeIndex);
                String player1      = cursor.getString(player1Index);
                String player2      = cursor.getString(player2Index);
                String team         = cursor.getString(teamIndex);
                String time         = cursor.getString(timeIndex);

                if (player2 != null) {
                    MatchEvent matchEvent = new MatchEvent(time, type, player1, player2, team);
                    result.add(matchEvent);
                } else {
                    MatchEvent matchEvent = new MatchEvent(time, type, player1, team);
                    result.add(matchEvent);
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

now in my RugbyActivity.class the part that does not work is this

```
int bpts = factsDbAdapter.countTriesWithMatchID(factsDbAdapter.KEY_MATCHID, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TEAM);
                        if (bpts<3)
```

can anyone help me or steer me in the right direction please better discription of the code below

```
switch (status) {
                case WIN: {// Team won the match.
                    int totalWins = teamAdapter.getColumnValueForTeamInt(teamAdapter.KEY_WINS, team);
                    int totalPoints = teamAdapter.getColumnValueForTeamInt(teamAdapter.KEY_TOTALPOINTS, team);
                    int totalBonusPoints = teamAdapter.getColumnValueForTeamInt(teamAdapter.KEY_BONUSPOINTS, team);
                    teamAdapter.updateSingleColumn(team, teamAdapter.KEY_WINS, totalWins + 1);
                    int bpts = factsDbAdapter.countTriesWithMatchID(factsDbAdapter.KEY_MATCHID, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TEAM);
                    if (bpts<3) {
                        teamAdapter.updateSingleColumn(team, teamAdapter.KEY_BONUSPOINTS, totalBonusPoints + 1);
                        teamAdapter.updateSingleColumn(team, teamAdapter.KEY_TOTALPOINTS, totalPoints + 5);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        teamAdapter.updateSingleColumn(team, teamAdapter.KEY_TOTALPOINTS, totalPoints + 4);
                    }
                    break;
                }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show the definition and value of `factsDbAdapter.KEY_MATCHID`.  Make sure it is an `int` and not a `String`.

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel Hi the value of factsDbAdapter.KEY_MATCHID should be any thing from 1 up to 100 depending on the amount of matches is recorded.

Comment: Yes, but is it a `String`?  Because an `int` is expected and Java does not automatically convert these types.  Please show that line of code.

Comment: @john16384 the line of code is as follows int bpts = factsDbAdapter.countTriesWithMatchID(factsDbAdapter.KEY_MATCHID, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TEAM); as I stated newby to android and do not know how to convert String to int all examples I looked at and tested does not work for me

Comment: If you want a solution, you really need to read what people are saying.  I asked several times now what type `factsDbAdapter.KEY_MATC‌​HID` is.  So go to the file where this is defined, and show me what it says there.  Either that or edit your answer and post the *entire* FactsDbAdapter file, not just an excerpt.

Comment: @john16384 my Apologies will be editing my FactsDbAdapter file for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method defined as:

```
public int countTriesWithMatchID(int match_id, String type, String teamName)
```

And you are calling it with:

```
factsDbAdapter.countTriesWithMatchID(factsDbAdapter.KEY_MATCHID, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE, factsDbAdapter.KEY_TEAM)
```

If you replace the constants you are using, the call becomes:

```
factsDbAdapter.countTriesWithMatchID("match_id", "type", "team")
```

However, this will not work because they are all of type `String`, while your `countTriesWithMatchID` expects an `int`, a `String` and another `String`.

So, the problem is that you need an `int` for first parameter, the id of the match.  A call like this would work, but you need the right id number:

```
factsDbAdapter.countTriesWithMatchID(1, "type", "team")
```

I hope this helps.